# `dtype`が`numpy.uint8`の配列をnumpy.arrayのインデックスに利用すると処理時間が長くなってしまいます。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: python, numpy

## 環境

- Python 3.11.2
- numpy 1.24.2

## やりたいこと

画像をPillowなどで読み込み、bool配列を使って、特定のピクセルを白色（`[255,255,255]`）にしたいです。

## 起きたこと

マスク用の配列の`dtype`を`bool`ではなく、間違えて`numpy.uint8`にしてしまいました。
そのマスク用の配列を利用して、特定のピクセルを白色に設定しようとしたら、処理時間が1分以上かかりました。

```
In [131]: height=1080; width=1920; channel=3

# Pillowなどで画像を読み込むことを想定
In [132]: data=numpy.random.randint(256, size=(height,width,channel))

In [133]: correct_mask = numpy.zeros((height, width), dtype=bool)

In [134]: %time data[correct_mask] = [255,255,255]
CPU times: user 773 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 773 µs
Wall time: 526 µs


# マスク用の配列の型を間違えて`numpy.uint8`にしてしまった
In [135]: wrong_mask = numpy.zeros((height, width), dtype=numpy.uint8)

# 処理に時間がかかる。なぜ？
In [136]: %time data[wrong_mask] = [255,255,255]
CPU times: user 2min 17s, sys: 0 ns, total: 2min 17s
Wall time: 2min 17s
```

## 質問

なぜ`dtype`が`numpy.uint8`の配列をインデックスに利用すると、`dtype`が`bool`の配列を利用するときと比較して、処理時間が長くなるのでしょうか
また、`dtype`が`numpy.uint8`の配列をインデックスに利用すると、どのような処理になるのでしょうか？

Comment: 単に `data[wrong_mask]` としてみてください。おそらくメモリエラーになるかと思います。`Unable to allocate 89.0 GiB for an array with shape (1080, 1920, 1920, 3) and data type int64` ここで、shape が `(1080, 1920, 1920, 3)` と表示されていて、次元が増えていることが処理時間が長くなってしまう原因です。

Comment: 確かにメモリエラーになりました。なぜ次元が増えるのでしょうか？ブロードキャストがよく分かっていません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> また、dtypeがnumpy.uint8の配列をインデックスに利用すると、どのような処理になるのでしょうか？

`Y[i]`とすれば`i`番目の要素が取れます。
`Y[[i]]`とインデックスをリストにすると、
最初の要素が`Y[i]`であるndarrayが取得できます。すなわち`[Y[i]]`
このような感じで、`Y[X]`とすると、(Xは整数配列)
Xの各要素x_iをY[x_i]に置き換えたndarrayが取得できます。
例えば`Y[ [[0,1],[2,3]] ]`は`[[Y[0],Y[1]],[Y[2],Y[3]]]`

これを踏まえて質問文の`data[wrong_mask]`を考えると、
`wrong_mask`の各要素は全部0ですので、
これは`wrong_mask`の各要素を`data[0]`で置き換えたものとなります。

`shape`は
`wrong_mask`が`(1080, 1920)`
`data[0]`が`(1920, 3)`ですから、

結果`data[wrong_mask]`は`(1080, 1920, 1920, 3)`になってしまいます。

[Indexing on ndarrays — NumPy v1.24 Manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

##### ブール配列のインデックス付け

ブール配列の使用例

```py
data[data[:, :, 1] == 0] = {255, 255, 255}   # RGBの緑の成分が無ければ白へ
data[data.sum(-1) < 32] = {255, 255, 255}   # RGB合計値が 32 未満(暗め) なら白へ
```

形状(`.shape`)の詳細を見てみると

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> height, width, channel = 1080, 1920, 3
>>> data = np.random.randint(256, size=(height, width, channel), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> data.shape
(1080, 1920, 3)
>>> filt = data[:, :, 1] == 0
>>> filt.shape, filt.dtype
((1080, 1920), dtype('bool'))
```

`data[filt]` の記述では, `filt` の次元の数は `data` より少ないので, `data[filt, ...]` と解釈される 
上記コードの場合, `data[filt, :]` ということになる(次元が一つ少ないため)

結果の形状については, `ヒットした件数 * 残りの次元` の形状(`.shape`) になり

```py
>>> filt.sum()
8100
>>> data[filt, :].shape
(8100, 3)
```

##### 整数配列のインデックス付け

演算では, ブール配列は整数配列と同様に演算可能 (上記の `filt.sum()` のように) だが,
indexing(インデックス付け) においては ブール配列と整数配列はまったくの別物

整数, 整数配列, スライスなどの使用例

```py
>>> data[100, 160]   # 座標指定
array([167, 167, 181], dtype=uint8)
>>> data[100, 160, 1]   # 座標と 緑のチャンネル
167
>>> data[0].shape   # 最初の一つの次元なら (このような指定の形状に意味があるとは思えないが)
(1920, 3)
```

仮に `(2,3,4)` の多次元配列での indexingなら, 残りの次元と合わせて 以下のような結果になる

```py
>>> nums = np.zeros((2, 3, 4), dtype=int)
>>> data[nums, :, :].shape   # data[nums] は残りの次元から data[nums, :, :] と同じ意味
(2, 3, 4, 1920, 3)
```

それぞれの `.shape` について, 少しまとめ

1. ブール配列の形状(`.shape`) は, もとの配列の (先頭に指定した場合)先頭から (途中または最後まで)合致している必要があり, `.ndim` の分の次元を指定したことになる
2. 整数配列の形状(`.shape`) は, **結果の形状**にのみ影響を与える

---

#### 処理が遅い理由

処理が遅い理由は, 上記とはまた(少し)別のところにある

`data[0]`, `data[3:7]` などの指定はビューが返され
`data[[0]]` などの高度なインデックス付け [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) はコピーが返される

```py
>>> data[[0]].base is None   # 「コピー」が返される
True
```

`data[[0, 0, 0, 0] + [1]*100]` のような整数配列では, `[0]` が `4`つ, `[1]` が `100` の分 内容が繰り返された ndarray が返される (ビューでは返しようがない)
代入であっても似たようなもので, `[0]` へ `4`回, `[1]` へ `100`回, 代入することになる

質問のコードで, 仮に `data[[0]]` の代入に 50マイクロ秒の時間がかかると仮定すると,
単純計算で, トータル `50μsec * 1000 * 2000` でほぼ 100秒の処理時間になる

それほど単純でないにしても, それに近い倍率で行われると予測できる
以下は Colabでの実行時間

```py
nums = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)
%timeit data[[0]] = (255,255,255)
# 20 µs ± 550 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit data[nums] = (255,255,255)
# 38.6 s ± 807 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

参考

- [NumPy quickstart](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html)
- [Indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)